# Quick sort using ARM assembly - segmentation error

Tags: c, assembly, arm

I'm trying to make a Quick Sort function using ARM assembly (Raspberry pi),

but it shows me segmentation error.

I think recursion process makes that error, while storing or loading with stacks.

Can you tell me how can I fix it?
I used ARM assembly code in https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Sorting/Quicksort#ARM_Assembly
here,

I just typed it same. Just changing registers like 'r3'->'r2', 'r2'->'r1', 'r1'->'r0' ...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define SIZE 32

int main()
{
int arr[SIZE];
int max, min;
int i;

for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    arr[i] = rand() % 100;
}

asm(
    "mov r0, #0\n\t"
    "mov r1, #128\n\t"
    "Loop3:\n\t"
    "stmfd sp!, {r3, r5, lr}\n\t"
    "mov r5, r1\n\t"

    "Loop4:\n\t"
    "sub r6, r5, r0\n\t"
    "cmp r6, #4\n\t"
    "ldmlefd sp!, {r3, r5, pc}\n\t"
    "ldr r6, [%[arr],r0]\n\t"
    "add r1, r0, #4\n\t"
    "mov r3, r5\n\t"

    "Loop5:\n\t"
    "ldr r2, [%[arr],r1]\n\t"
    "cmp r2, r6\n\t"
    "addle r1, r1, #4\n\t"
    "ble Loop6\n\t"
    "sub r3, r3, #4\n\t"
    "ldr r4, [%[arr],r3]\n\t"
    "str r4, [%[arr],r1]\n\t"
    "str r2, [%[arr],r3]\n\t"

    "Loop6:\n\t"
    "cmp r1, r3\n\t"
    "blt Loop5\n\t"

    "Loop7:\n\t"
    "sub r1, r1, #4\n\t"
    "ldr r2, [%[arr],r1]\n\t"
    "str r2, [%[arr],r0]\n\t"
    "str r6, [%[arr],r1]\n\t"
    "bl Loop3\n\t"
    "mov r0, r3\n\t"
    "b Loop4\n\t"

    :
:
    [arr] "r"(arr)
    :
    "r0", "r1", "r2", "r3", "r4", "r5", "r6"
    );
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You inline asm can never reach the end of the asm template.  Presumably you're trying to return out of the C function, not just the internal recursive calls.  That's obviously unsafe because there's zero guarantee about stack layout or the contents of LR, and that will change with/without optimization.

**Don't write a whole recursive in the middle of a C function.**

Use a debugger to single-step the resulting program and see where your code breaks the compiler-generated asm that surrounds it.

---

Also your inline asm is broken: you dereference `arr` without specifying it as a memory read/write input or a `"memory"` clobber.  A pointer input does *not* imply that the pointed-to memory is also an operand.